# Android KeyPairGenerator + php openssl_public_encrypt

Tags: java, php, android, openssl, rsa

I have a client (android device) that generates a public+private key pair. It sends the public key to a server and the server should encrypt some data using the public key and return it so the client can decrypt it using the private key later. My php code logs a warning stating that the public key I am providing it is invalid.

On the device side, I generate the key pair as follows -

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(256);
KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
PublicKey publicKey = kp.getPublic();
```

I then base64 encode and POST it -

```
String urlParameters = "productID=" + productID + "&publicKey="
                + URLEncoder.encode(Base64.encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded(),
                        Base64.DEFAULT)); // without the URLEncoder, the + signs
                                          // are turned into spaces
```

On the server side, I extract the publicKey from the POST parameters and try to use it for encoding some data -

```
$publicKey = $_POST['publicKey'];
$encryptedData = '';
$productData = 'test test test';
openssl_public_encrypt($productData, $encryptedData, $publicKey);
```

This ends up erroring out with the following in the log -

```
PHP Warning:  openssl_public_encrypt(): key parameter is not a valid public key
```

I have also tried adding prefix and suffix to the public key before using it for encryption but that did not help either -

```
$publicKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n" . $publicKey . "\r\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
```

Have broken my head over this for a while and none of the suggestions I came across online seem to help. Any thoughts would be most helpful!

Comment: *sighs*... how does PHP get away with such poor documentation? The [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php) doesn't even say what format the public key should be in!

Comment: Note that sending a public key to another party is not enough to avoid man in the middle attacks; how do you know that the public key is from the right party? Anybody may send you a public key...

Comment: @owlstead: you have a good point there. i was sending a public key to the server so i could avoid hardcoding/bundling private key on the device side by generating them on the fly. if i instead use a symmetric key and not pass it around, i am concerned that the key may be extracted from the android package. need to think over this some more i guess..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve the issue finally by making 2 changes -

1. Had to use the `Base64.NO_WRAP` flag instead of `Base64.DEFAULT` on the Java side.
2. Added the prefix/suffix in php after chunk splitting -  `$publicKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n" . chunk_split($publicKey) . "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";`